# Custom OpenCV build works in command prompt but not working in Pycharm 2022.3.1?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, dllimport

Last December I've compiled OpenCV 4.6.0 with contrib modules + cuda support with cMake in a conda environment called **opencv-460+cuda** with **python 3.9.15 and numpy 1.23.5**. The cuda version installed is the **cuda_11.0.3_451.82_win10** with **cudnn-11.0-windows-x64-v8.0.5.39**. Then I configured my previosly installed Pycharm 2021.2 to execute my own cv2 based scripts and all worked like a digital heaven. Only had to proper config these: [image: paths].

Then one day I've decide to install CUDA v9.0 because Re3 object tracking algorithm requirement and it worked just fine alongside the v11.0 after settings the correct order in the environment variables panel [image: (Current system variables)]

And lastly I choose to compile Marlin 2.1(yes, for 3D printers) with Visual Studio Code and after this, things got weird.

I couldn't execute cv2 scripts inside Pycharm nor the Anaconda Prompt with env **opencv-460+cuda** activated due to

> import cv2
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: Couldn't find the specified module.

Then I get Windows to a past point using its restoration tool. It removed the CUDA v9.0(not the files) and the Visual Studio Code. And now the opencv scripts work in the Anaconda Prompt and in Windows PS but not in Pycharm 2022.3

I have even installed cuda v9.0 again and I still can execute my cv2 programs in Anaconda Prompt but not in Pycharm and I want to know what the h3ll have VS Code done to my Windows

I have even run Dependency Walker on the **cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd** file and I've got these [image: Dependency Walker Output]. It finds all DLLs but in Checksum column says **incorrect** for the first three elements, altough when I put the caret on top of them appears the next
[image: caret display]

And other odd behavior is when I use **Terminal** from Pycharm I can import cv2 [image: cv2 in Pycharm Terminal] and even execute scripts but I can't execute it with Pycharm console and I WANT THE WAY THINGS WERE BEFORE VS CODE

Comment: How did you build OpenCV?

Comment: With Cmake GUI following this excelent guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsmhKar8oOc&list=PLUE9cBml08yhivR1J7ULJ1V8PsXUKoMLB, but using opencv 4.6.0 with python 3.9.15 instead